# How to convert in Prometheus's data the attribute to value?

Tags: prometheus

I have data in Prometheus like this:

```
test{success="true", ...} 1
test{success="true", ...} 1
test{success="false", ...} 1
```

I'd like to convert it to something like this:

```
test{...} 1
test{...} 1
test{...} 0
```

Is there any function to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus only supports float64 as values, not strings, so this isn't possible.

The convention in Prometheus is that 0 is false and 1 is true, so a better way to expose this would be:

```
test_passed{...} 1
test_passed{...} 1
test_passed{...} 0
```

Comment: Ok, I've changed desired format. But how to prepare this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should change the server to expose it directly as you want it (because as you can tell it's not all that useful in the form it is exposed right now).

But short of that you could use an expression like this:

```
sum without(success) (test{success="true"} or test{success="false"} * 0)
```

Of course, this assumes the rest of your labels (the `...` part of your example) uniquely identify each series (which is sort of implied by your question).